# What's wrong with my code in Python 2.7.9?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have just started learning python and written a procedure to calculate factorial of a number. I am getting a logical error. The value returned by `fact` function is `None` and the value of `factorial` after execution is 24.

```
factorial = 1

def fact(num) :
    if num == 0 :
        return 1
    global factorial
    print factorial
    factorial *= num
    if num-1 > 1 :
        fact(num - 1)
    else :
        return factorial

print fact(4)
print factorial
```

Output :

```
1
4
12
None
24
```

Comment: You should return the recursive call's return value, `return fact(num - 1)`. You might also want to look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30214677/1903116)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Recursive function does not return specified value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27691547/recursive-function-does-not-return-specified-value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change

```
if num-1 > 1 :
    fact(num - 1)
else:
    return factorial
```

to:

```
if num-1 > 1 :
    return fact(num - 1)
else :
    return factorial
```

The problem was you were not returning anything except for the base case.