# Why is this an infinite recursion?

Tags: c++, recursion

I wrote the following function to find out the number of paths we can reach from the start cell `(0,0)` to the destination cell `(n,n)`.  I cannot, for the life of me, figure out why this is infinite recursion.

Code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int numOfPathsToDestUtil(int start, int end, int noOfPaths, int n) {
  cout<<"Start: "<<start<<" and end: "<<end<<"and n: "<<n<<"\n";
  if(start==end && start==n)
    return noOfPaths;

  if(end<start)
    return 0;

  numOfPathsToDestUtil(start+1, end, noOfPaths+1,n) + numOfPathsToDestUtil(start, end+1, noOfPaths+1,n);
}

int numOfPathsToDest( int n ) 
{
  cout<<"n is: "<<n<<"\n";
  return numOfPathsToDestUtil(0,0,0,n);
}

int main() {
  int ans = numOfPathsToDest(4);
  cout<<ans;

  return 0;
}
```

Note:  I am not requesting help with the code (saying so, because conditions like `end<start` are implementation-specific.  Request you to let me understand why this recursion does not stop:

> n is: 4 
>   Start: 0 and end: 0and n: 4
>   Start: 1 and end: 0and n: 4
>   Start: 0 and end: 1and n: 4
>   Start: 1 and end: 1and n: 4
>   Start: 2 and end: 1and n: 4
>   Start: 1 and end: 2and n: 4
>   Start: 2 and end: 2and n: 4
>   Start: 3 and end: 2and n: 4
>   Start: 2 and end: 3and n: 4
>   Start: 3 and end: 3and n: 4
>   Start: 4 and end: 3and n: 4
>   Start: 3 and end: 4and n: 4
>   Start: 4 and end: 4and n: 4  --> I expect it to stop here as start=end and start=n
>   Start: 3 and end: 5and n: 4
>   Start: 4 and end: 5and n: 4
>   Start: 5 and end: 5and n: 4
>   Start: 6 and end: 5and n: 4
>   Start: 5 and end: 6and n: 4
>   Start: 6 and end: 6and n: 4

Thank you so much!

Comment: Debugger should make short work of this.

Comment: @user4581301, yes I am trying to learn using a debugger as well side-by-side.

Comment: Or maybe not even that ,much work. `numOfPathsToDestUtil` is missing a return statement.

Comment: It does have two return statements (and as seen in the output, they are reached _always_).

Comment: If they are reached always why do you have a recursive call after them?

Comment: And using a return statement as well doesn't help.  `:(` I already tried it.

Comment: In that case you have two bugs. You need that return.

Comment: @user4581301, I mean, always reached for the program to stop - they are the base cases.  That is why I don't expect this to be infinite.

Comment: Okay, but that doesn't help either.  Still infinite: http://ideone.com/RicviH

Comment: The problem is that you have two recursive calls. The place you marked is where one of them reached the base case, but the other one never does.

Comment: @user4581301, also what two bugs?  Could you kindly elaborate?

Comment: @UmedhSinghBundela There's the bug that's causing the infinite recursion, and the bug where you're not returning the value returned by the recursive calls.

Comment: @Barmar, oh.. Interesting.. Didn't think about that.  Any tips to handle it please?

Comment: The second bug is that the last line of the function should be `return numOfPathsToDestUtil(start+1, end, noOfPaths+1,n) + numOfPathsToDestUtil(start, end+1, noOfPaths+1,n);`

Comment: Not all paths of numOfPathsToDestUtil() return a value. Didn't your compiler warn about that?

Comment: @UmedhSinghBundela Make sure that the parameters to the recusive call always get you closer to the base case.

Comment: @Barmar, yes, but even including a `return` statement there makes it infinite: http://ideone.com/RicviH.  And I don't fully understand, why are return there?

Comment: A function must always return or it is ill-formed. Weird things will happen.

Comment: If you don't put a return there, then you do the addition but you never pass the result back to the caller. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27691547/recursive-function-does-not-return-specified-value

Comment: @Barmar: _Make sure that the parameters to the recusive call always get you closer to the base case._ - could you please elaborate, sir?

Comment: @UmedhSinghBundela Actually, in graph walking like this, what you have to do is make sure you don't visit a node that you've already been to before, because then you'll keep repeating the path out of that node. So you need to make a list of all the nodes you've been to, and return if you ever get to one of them again.

Comment: @Barmar, yes, that makes sense.  But then isn't doing a `+1` to the `start` and `end` variables taking me closer to the base case (my first check)?  And also, as in the output I am only incrementing the values of `start` and `end` so not visiting the nodes again and again.

Comment: @UmedhSinghBundela Think of recursive factorial. Each recursive call subtracts 1, getting you closer to 0, which is the base case where the recursion stops.

Comment: `start+1` gets you closer to the base case, which is `start > end`. But `end+1` takes you further away, because `end` stays higher than `start`.

Comment: @Barmar, oh, so you mean `start+1` takes me towards the base case of `start==end and start=n`; but then `end+1` again makes the target move ahead resulting in an infinite loop - correct?

Comment: Interesting.  It makes sense.  Thank you! :)

Comment: Look at the values printed on the lines after you thought it should stop. You can see the numbers getting higher. And they're higher than `n`, so `start == n` will never be true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's label your calls

```
numOfPathsToDestUtil(0,0,0,n) # original (O)
numOfPathsToDestUtil(start+1, end, noOfPaths+1,n) # first-recursive (FR)
numOfPathsToDestUtil(start, end+1, noOfPaths+1,n) # second-recursive (SR)
```

Your output:

```
n is: 4 
Start: 0 and end: 0and n: 4        # O - numOfPathsToDestUtil(0,0,0,4)
Start: 1 and end: 0and n: 4        # FR -  numOfPathsToDestUtil(0+1,0,0,4)
Start: 0 and end: 1and n: 4        # SR - numOfPathsToDestUtil(0,0+1,0,4)
Start: 1 and end: 1and n: 4        # SR -> FR
Start: 2 and end: 1and n: 4        # SR -> FR -> FR
Start: 1 and end: 2and n: 4        # SR -> FR -> SR
Start: 2 and end: 2and n: 4        # SR -> FR -> SR -> FR
Start: 3 and end: 2and n: 4        # SR -> FR -> SR -> FR -> FR
Start: 2 and end: 3and n: 4        # SR -> FR -> SR -> FR -> SR
Start: 3 and end: 3and n: 4        # SR -> FR -> SR -> FR -> SR -> FR
Start: 4 and end: 3and n: 4        # SR -> FR -> SR -> FR -> SR -> FR -> FR
Start: 3 and end: 4and n: 4        # SR -> FR -> SR -> FR -> SR -> FR -> SR
Start: 4 and end: 4and n: 4        # SR -> FR -> SR -> FR -> SR -> FR -> SR -> FR (stops and returns value)
Start: 3 and end: 5and n: 4        # SR -> FR -> SR -> FR -> SR -> FR -> SR -> SR (never reaches where end==4 and n==4, keeps going and going)
Start: 4 and end: 5and n: 4
Start: 5 and end: 5and n: 4
Start: 6 and end: 5and n: 4
Start: 5 and end: 6and n: 4
Start: 6 and end: 6and n: 4
```

Answer (score 1):

How to debug: I will suggest you to draw a calling tree

- You are missing return statement on this line

  numOfPathsToDestUtil(start+1, end, noOfPaths+1,n) + numOfPathsToDestUtil(start, end+1, noOfPaths+1,n);
- Consider numOfPathsToDestUtil(start, end+1, noOfPaths+1,n) only.
  Initial value (start,end) will be (0,0) then calling => (0,1) => then calling (0,2) => (0,3) =>(0,4) =>(0,5)... no termination constraint on end. This part will go into infinite loop
- Now let's consider as a whole (hope below explanation is easy for you to understand)

Init(start, end,n, status)

```
(0,0,4,calling)
=>(1,0,4, will end)+(0,1,4,calling)
=>(1,1,4,calling)+(0,2, 4,calling)
=>(2,1,4,will end)+(1,2,4,calling)+(0,2, 4,calling)
=>(1,2,4,calling)+(0,2, 4,calling)
=>(2,2,4,calling)+(1,3,4,calling) +(0,2,4,calling)
```

I think you are able to derive the rest, and it shows that your recursion will not easily get out.

You need to modify your constraint to ensure what only "desired" condition will continue with recursion.

- if end > n, will you continue recursion?
- if start == end but start < n will continue recursion?

I will not list all. Hope it provide you a good thinking direction.

Comment: I understood.  Thank you for your help! :)  I wish I could accept your answer as well.