# Array is empty after loop in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I am trying to make an `ARRAY` of files and subfolder inside a specific folder. I got success in getting a list of files and subfolders but when I try kept this data in an `ARRAY` it only show result as expected within `LOOP`. Once `LOOP` finished it `return EMPTY`

Here is full code

```
<?php
function dirToOptions($path = '../data/vid/', $level = 0) {
    $items = scandir($path);
    $vidCount = 0; $thumbCount = 0;
    foreach($items as $item) {
        // ignore items strating with a dot (= hidden or nav)
        if (strpos($item, '.') === 0) {
            continue;
        }

        $fullPath = $path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $item;
        // add some whitespace to better mimic the file structure
        $item = str_repeat('&nbsp;', $level * 3) . $item;
        // file
        if (is_file($fullPath)) {
            $rrInt = (int)$level-1;
            if($rrInt == 0){
                $vid['videos'][] = array('name'=>$item, 'link'=>$fullPath);
                echo "<a href='$fullPath'><i for='$rrInt'>$item</i></a><br />";
            }elseif($rrInt == 1){
                $thumb['thumbs'][] = array('name'=>$item, 'link'=>$fullPath);
                echo "<a href='$fullPath'><i for='$rrInt'>$item</i></a><br />";
                var_dump($thumb); //SHOW RESULT HERE
            }
        }
        // dir
        else if (is_dir($fullPath)) {
            // immediatly close the optgroup to prevent (invalid) nested optgroups
            echo "<b label='$level'>$item</b><br />";
            // recursive call to self to add the subitems
            dirToOptions($fullPath, $level + 1);
        }
    }
}

$array = array(); $vid = array(); $thumb = array();

echo '<div>';
dirToOptions();
echo '</div>';

var_dump($vid); // RETURN EMPTY
?>
```

> Thanks to all for support but at last I prefer to use `GLOBAL VARS`

Comment: Ummm... What is `$vid`? Of course it's empty `$vid = array()`

Comment: its simply an empty VAR

Comment: How do you think the content should get to the array?

Comment: You're not using the return value of the recursive call.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27691547/recursive-function-does-not-return-specified-value

Comment: its not correct reference dude

Comment: Using a global var is almost never the preferred solution, and at least not for something like this which can easily be written a much more portable and maintainable way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The EASY answer is to add the line:

```
global $vid;
```

To the beginning of your function.  This will extend the scope of $vid outside of your function.

Though, I would HEARTILY recommend you follow the other instructions, and return the array from the function instead.

Answer (score 1):

See [PHP - Variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).  The `$vid` defined with `$vid = array();` is not available inside the function and the `$vid` defined inside is not available outside.  You probably want to `return` it at the end of the function:

```
return $vid;
```

Then assign the return and use it:

```
$vid = dirToOptions();
var_dump($vid);
```

But it looks like you're going to have the same issue with `$thumb`, so change it to use the `$vid` array:

```
        }elseif($rrInt == 1){
            $vid['thumbs'][] = array('name'=>$item, 'link'=>$fullPath);
            echo "<a href='$fullPath'><i for='$rrInt'>$item</i></a><br />";
```

Comment: check the quoted portion [just updated] of question again

Comment: That's not complete code and you are not assigning anything to `$array`.

Comment: I am assigning dude, just a sec i gonna update the question

Comment: check now buddy

Comment: its also weird for me, how its not working? please help dude

Answer (score -1):

The variables inside and outside of a function are different variables, even if they are named the same. This is what's called the variable's scope. This way your function keeps all its state internally, and doesn't affect anything outside of the function definition (by accident). This makes it harder to introduce bugs because you happened to use the same variable name inside a function as outside it.

The solution is to return the value from the function after building the array inside it:

```
function dirToOptions($path = '../data/vid/', $level = 0) {
    $vid = array();

    ....

    return $vid;
}

$vid = dirToOptions();
var_dump($vid);
```

That way everything regarding how dirToOptions work is kept isolated, and you only process the content returned from the function. The interface to the function and what is does is kept clean from any external dependencies.

To handle the recursive part of your code, merge the values returned in each step - or pass a parameter by reference. Using a reference is explicit in the method signature and doesn't blindly create a reference to a variable from the global scope (and can be passed as a local variable from a different function if necessary).

```
function dirToOptions($path = '../data/vid/', $level = 0) {
    $vid = array();

    ....
    } else {
        // merge this array and the one returned from the child directory
        $vid = array_merge($vid, dirToOptions($fullPath, $level + 1));
    }

    return $vid;
}

$vid = dirToOptions();
```

.. and as a reference:

```
function dirToOptions(&$vid, $path = '../data/vid/', $level = 0) {
    $vid = array();

    ....
    } else {
        // pass the reference on further down the recursive calls
        dirToOptions($vid, $fullPath, $level + 1);
    }

    return $vid;
}

dirToOptions($vid);
```

Comment: check the quoted portion [just updated] of question again

Comment: Using `global` is bad, as this breaks the promise from your function that it isn't going to change anything outside itself. If you _do_ want to do something like that, do it by passing a variable as a reference. For future reference I've updated my answer to show you how you can solve it both with a reference and by just keeping the return values.

Comment: I appreciate  your suggestion but  problem is that its not working in my case, don't know why.

Comment: Probably because you're not considering the recursive function call you have inside your code, which I've added examples for. If you wrote this code originally, you should have a decent grasp of the flow of it.