# fetch() call not returning any data

Tags: javascript, ajax, vue.js, fetch-api

I'm having a problem with my fetch() call not working correctly. I have a recursion method that calls itself within this function, but once it passes the if statement, the data itself is not being resolved to the .then() call below. I would like to keep the recursion method within this function. Because the system that this function is calling will change the data.result to a different result that is not null. I just don't know when that will happen, hence that is why I'm using the recursion method.

```
var someToken = "actually token";

function getResult(getToken) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fetch(url, {
      headers: {
        "Authorization": something,
        "Jenkins-Crumb": getToken
      },
      redirect: 'follow',

    }).then(response => {
      return response.json()

    }).then(data => {

      if (data.result == null) {
        console.log('retrieving data')
        getResult(getToken)
      } else if (data.result == "SUCCESS") {
        console.log('success')
        resolve(data)
      }

    }).catch(err => {
      reject(err)
    })
  })
}

getResult(someToken).then(data => {
  console.log(data)
}).catch(err => console.log(err))
```

Comment: You need `return getResult(getToken)`

Comment: This might be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27691547/recursive-function-does-not-return-specified-value but I'm not sure if that's right for async code.

Comment: Returning the recursive `getResult` alone wouldn't be enough because he's using the explicit Promise construction antipattern

Comment: Yeah, I had a feeling it wasn't so simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using `async...await` and your code will be much simpler

```js
var someToken = "actually token";

async function getResult(getToken) {
  const resp = await fetch(url, {
    headers: {
      "Authorization": something,
      "Jenkins-Crumb": getToken
    },
    redirect: 'follow',
  });
  const data = await resp.json();
  if (data.result == null) {
    console.log('retrieving data')
    return getResult(getToken)
  } else if (data.result == "SUCCESS") {
    console.log('success')
    return data;
  }
}

getResult(someToken).then(data => {
  console.log(data)
}).catch(err => console.log(err))
```

Comment: This actually works for code. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 3):

You need to return the recursive call of `getResult` *and* avoid the [explicit Promise construction antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743) (just `return` the Promises instead):

```
function getResult(getToken) {
  return fetch(url, {
    headers: {
      "Authorization": something,
      "Jenkins-Crumb": getToken
    },
    redirect: 'follow',
  })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      if (data.result == null) {
        console.log('retrieving data');
        return getResult(getToken); // <-----------------------------
      } else if (data.result == "SUCCESS") {
        console.log('success');
        return data; // <-------------------------------------------
      }
      // What if data.result is neither null nor SUCCESS?  <--------
    });
}

getResult(someToken).then(data => {
  console.log(data);
}).catch(err => console.log(err))
```

Live demo:

```js
const getUrl = () => Math.random() < 0.25 ? 'data:,{"result":"SUCCESS"}' : 'data:,{}';

function getResult(getToken) {
  return fetch(getUrl(), {
    headers: {
      "Authorization": 'something',
      "Jenkins-Crumb": getToken
    },
    redirect: 'follow',
  })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      if (data.result == null) {
        console.log('retrieving data');
        return getResult(getToken); // <-----------------------------
      } else if (data.result == "SUCCESS") {
        console.log('success');
        return data; // <-------------------------------------------
      }
      // What if data.result is neither null nor SUCCESS?  <--------
    });
}

getResult('someToken').then(data => {
  console.log(data);
}).catch(err => console.log(err))
```

You should also consider - your `if` and `else if`s at the end of the `.then` may not encompass all possibilities. What if `data.result` is neither `null` nor `'SUCCESS'`? Given your current logic, the `getResult` call will result in `data` being `undefined` in the consumer. If there's a chance of that happening, you might want to throw an error or something in that case.

```
if (data.result == null) {
  console.log('retrieving data')
  return getResult(getToken) // <-----------------------
} else if (data.result == "SUCCESS") {
  console.log('success')
  return data; // <-----------------------
}
throw new Error('data.result is neither null nor 'SUCCESS'');
```

Comment: I tried using this method but it didn't return the data that I wanted in the function below. But thank you so much for the help. Maybe I didn't use your solution correctly.

Comment: Works fine here, see snippet and https://jsfiddle.net/6jutqna5/