call same function in python recursively and parallelly with list of strings
I have a list of users i.e
user_list=["user1","user2","user3"]
I have a function called search which search the user and their manager and then manager's manager and so on till it reaches the CEO level, who doesn't have any manager.
At the end i have to return each user's manager and their managers.
user_list =["user1","user2","user3","user4","user5"]

def search(user):
    user_details = ldap.search(user)
    user_manager = user_details["manager"]
    new_user = user_manager
    list_of_user_managers.append(new_user)
    if new_user["manager"] == "None":
       return list_of_user_managers
    else:
       return search(new_user)

where user_details has below data.
user_details = {
    'ntid': 'tom', 
    'ldap_owner': 'roy', 
    'ldap_manager': 'noman', 
    'ldap_email': 'austin@xyz.com'
}

After Search I am expecting results like:

user1 hierarchy : manager1, manager2 , manager3 , manager4
Consider manager1 as level1 manager of user1 and manager2 as manager1's manager.
user2 hierarchy : manager11, manager22 , manager33 , manager44
Consider manager11 as level1 manager of user2 and manager22 as manager11's manager.

I need to rewrite the above function, so that it accepts user from list of users and also parallely.

Can you add some data also to your original question in order to understand your question better? Examples could have for example a table of the data before the search and another table of the data after the search.

Where do you add to list_of_user_managers?

Your code doesn't return anything in the cases where it needs to recurse. This is a common beginner recursion error, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27691547/recursive-function-does-not-return-specified-value

Don't use a string "None" to indicate no manager. Use the special Python value None.

@anoach updated.

@Barmar within the function itself i need to append to list_of_managers and return it for each user.

def ldap_search(user):
    ldap_data = {
        "user1": {'ntid': 'user1', 'ldap_owner': 'roy', 'ldap_manager': 'manager1', 'ldap_email': 'user1@xyz.com'},
        "user2": {'ntid': 'user2', 'ldap_owner': 'roy', 'ldap_manager': 'manager11', 'ldap_email': 'user2@xyz.com'},
        "user3": {'ntid': 'user3', 'ldap_owner': 'roy', 'ldap_manager': 'manager21', 'ldap_email': 'user3@xyz.com'},
        "user4": {'ntid': 'user4', 'ldap_owner': 'roy', 'ldap_manager': 'manager31', 'ldap_email': 'user4@xyz.com'},
        "user5": {'ntid': 'user5', 'ldap_owner': 'roy', 'ldap_manager': 'manager41', 'ldap_email': 'user5@xyz.com'},
        "manager1": {'ntid': 'manager1', 'ldap_owner': 'roy', 'ldap_manager': 'manager2', 'ldap_email': 'manager1@xyz.com'},
        "manager2": {'ntid': 'manager2', 'ldap_owner': 'roy', 'ldap_manager': 'manager3', 'ldap_email': 'manager2@xyz.com'},
        "manager3": {'ntid': 'manager3', 'ldap_owner': 'roy', 'ldap_manager': 'manager4', 'ldap_email': 'manager3@xyz.com'},
        "manager4": {'ntid': 'manager4', 'ldap_owner': 'roy', 'ldap_manager': 'CEO', 'ldap_email': 'manager4@xyz.com'},
        "manager11": {'ntid': 'manager11', 'ldap_owner': 'roy', 'ldap_manager': 'manager22', 'ldap_email': 'manager11@xyz.com'},
        "manager22": {'ntid': 'manager22', 'ldap_owner': 'roy', 'ldap_manager': 'manager33', 'ldap_email': 'manager22@xyz.com'},
        "manager33": {'ntid': 'manager33', 'ldap_owner': 'roy', 'ldap_manager': 'manager44', 'ldap_email': 'manager33@xyz.com'},
        "manager44": {'ntid': 'manager44', 'ldap_owner': 'roy', 'ldap_manager': 'CEO', 'ldap_email': 'manager44@xyz.com'},
        "manager21": {'ntid': 'manager21', 'ldap_owner': 'roy', 'ldap_manager': 'manager31', 'ldap_email': 'manager21@xyz.com'},
        "manager31": {'ntid': 'manager31', 'ldap_owner': 'roy', 'ldap_manager': 'manager41', 'ldap_email': 'manager31@xyz.com'},
        "manager41": {'ntid': 'manager41', 'ldap_owner': 'roy', 'ldap_manager': 'CEO', 'ldap_email': 'manager41@xyz.com'},
        "CEO": {'ntid': 'CEO', 'ldap_owner': 'roy', 'ldap_manager': 'None', 'ldap_email': 'CEO@xyz.com'}
    }
    return ldap_data.get(user, {})

def search(user):
    user_details = ldap_search(user)
    manager = user_details.get("ldap_manager")
    if manager == None or manager == "CEO":
        return [user]
    else:
        return [user] + search(manager)

def search_user_list(user_list):
    result = []
    for user in user_list:
        managers = search(user)
        result.append(managers)
    return result

user_list = ["user1", "user2", "user3", "user4", "user5"]
ret = search_user_list(user_list)
print('\n'.join([str(i) for i in ret]))


The question asks how to do all the searches in parallel, so you need to use a multiprocessing pool
